# Weird resonating noise coming from electric guitar bridge only when playing a C

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, noise

two days ago I noticed my guitar making a strange noise when plucking certain strings on certain frets. Watching the issue more closely, I realized that it only happens when I play a C anywhere (e.g. low E8, low E20, A15, D10, D22, G17 [notation?]). The effect seems to be stronger on higher frets and doesn't seem to occur on the B or high E strings at all. The sound seems to be coming from the bridge. It is definitely not a fret buzzing.

Here's a recording of the noise: https://voca.ro/1dlq268wqzd6

Here's what my bridge looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOebF.jpg

The guitar in question is a PRS SE Standard 24 that I got a few weeks ago. The only thing I messed with in the past few days was the intonation, since it seemed to be a bit off. As far as I know, the noise only started happening afterwards. I don't really understand why it doesn't seem to happen on the higher strings, maybe it has something to do with string gauge. Since the noise started, I tried tightening some of the screws on the bridge since a few of them seemed to be looser than the rest but it didn't seem to help.

Cheers

Edit: I opened up the backside and played around with the two screws holding the plate that the springs are fixed to. It seems like they weren't quite symmetrical, the noise appeared to lessen when I tightened one screw over the other. It seems like my problem is fixed for now, but can anyone explain to me what was going wrong here?

Edit 2: Seems like I haven't quite fixed it. Playing around with those screws seems to do *something*, but I haven't quite found the sweet spot. It's trial and error at this point.

Comment: Play the offending note, and touch individual items round the bridge area. Bear in mind it may be something inside the guitar - like a loose component or pot.

Comment: It seemed to get better when I tightened a screw behind the backside cover. The noise appears to be gone for now

Comment: And if it's loosened again, would the sound return?

Comment: Haven't been able to make rhyme or reason of it, it seems kind of random.

Comment: These kind of things happen with all instruments. A loose part can buzz only for certain notes because the wavelength frequency of that pitch matches the physical qualities of the loose part. For instance, a sound wave might push it outward, and as it springs back, the gap is just perfect to let it meet the next sound wave, so it amplifies its own motion. On violin, I once tracked a student's buzz to a small bit of decorative inlay on a tuning peg that had come unglued.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, how do I go about tracking the sound? The noise seems to stop once I touch one of the springs in the back (https://i.imgur.com/IhTYYKr.jpeg). However, there are no screws or anything attached to the spring that I could tighten.

Comment: If it's the tremolo spring, there are tricks to mute them with foam, rubber sleeves, etc. Even taking the spring off and putting it back again could settle it in place.

Comment: Trial and error seemed to do the trick eventually. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue with C note with the same PRS guitar, I put inside tissue which is muting the springs and problem is gone.

Comment: This seems like a useful answer but it's not very clear. Can you edit to explain a bit more about what you did with the tissue and the springs?